# React-Apollo: Query with variables causes the UI to no longer be optimistic

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, optimistic-ui

I'm writing a React component using Apollo GraphQL (with React Apollo Hooks, but this makes no difference).

Here is my query:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(ListContacts, {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
  // variables: { limit: 1000 }
});
```

And here is my function that does the mutation:

```
const createContact = useMutation(gql(mutations.createContact));
const deleteContact = useMutation(gql(mutations.deleteContact));
const updateContact = useMutation(gql(mutations.updateContact));

async function handleContactSave(contact) {
  const isEmpty = allStringFieldsAreEmptyFromContact(contact);
  const { id, ...processedContact } = replaceEmptyStringsWithNull(contact);
  const idIsInArray = includesContactWithId(id)(contacts);

  try {
    if (isEmpty) {
      if (idIsInArray) {
        await deleteContact({
          variables: { input: { id } },
          optimisticResponse: () => ({ deleteContact: { id } }),
          update: (cache, { data: { deleteContact } }) => {
            const query = ListContacts;
            const data = cache.readQuery({ query });
            data.listContacts.items = data.listContacts.items.filter(
              item => item.id !== deleteContact.id
            );
            cache.writeQuery({ query, data });
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (idIsInArray) {
        await updateContact({
          variables: { input: { id, ...processedContact } },
          optimisticResponse: () => ({
            updateContact: { __typename: 'Contact', id, ...processedContact }
          }),
          update: (cache, { data: { updateContact } }) => {
            const query = ListContacts;
            const data = cache.readQuery({ query });
            data.listContacts.items = [
              ...data.listContacts.items.filter(
                item => item.id !== updateContact.id
              ),
              updateContact
            ];
            cache.writeQuery({ query, data });
          }
        });
      } else {
        await createContact({
          variables: { input: { ...processedContact } },
          optimisticResponse: () => ({
            createContact: {
              __typename: 'Contact',
              id: uuid(),
              ...processedContact
            }
          }),
          update: (cache, { data: { createContact } }) => {
            const query = ListContacts;
            const data = cache.readQuery({ query });
            data.listContacts.items = [
              ...data.listContacts.items.filter(
                item => item.id !== createContact.id
              ),
              createContact
            ];
            cache.writeQuery({ query, data });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

As soon as I comment out the `variables` key with the `limit` the UI does not update optimistically any more. With the value commented out it does. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writeQuery` method also accepts a `variables` value. Every combination of `query` and `variables` is treated as a separate query by Apollo. So if one `Query` component (or hook) uses a limit of `100` and another uses a limit of `50`, when writing your `update` function, you'll need to call `writeQuery` for both of these queries, passing in a different value for `variables` each time:

```
cache.writeQuery({ query, data, variables: { limit: 100 } })
cache.writeQuery({ query, data, variables: { limit: 50 } })
```

This is a [know limitation of the client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1546). In effect, you need to keep track of the variables through local state in order to correctly call `writeQuery` when your `update` function is called. This can be, understandably, a huge hassle. Luckily, you can utilize [apollo-link-watched-mutation](https://github.com/haytko/apollo-link-watched-mutation) to get around the issue.